# Como hacer consulta con clave foránea en Django

Tags: python, django

estoy haciendo un filtrado que me muestre los servicios del catálogo según el tipo de servicio

la estructura es la siguiente el catálogo tiene servicios y los servicios tiene tipo de servicios, quiero que solo se muestren los servicios en el catalogo que tenga el id tipo de servicio 1 y 2

```
 catalogo = Catalogo.objects.filter(servicio_id.tipo_servicio_id = 1).filter(servicio_id.tipo_servicio_id = 2)
```

pero no encuentra el parametro

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que para próximas preguntas incluyas mas información, como por ejemplo el contendido del models.py.

Suponiendo que tu modelo de catalogo tiene una llave foránea y que esta tiene el atributo "tipo_servicio_id", puedes intentar utilizar "__in" ojo que es con doble guion bajo.

```
catalogo = Catalogo.objects.filter(servicio_id.tipo_servicio_id__in = [1, 2])
```

Claramente puedes pasarle una variable para que no poner directamente la lista como por ejemplo

```
lista_id = [1, 2]
catalogo = Catalogo.objects.filter(servicio_id.tipo_servicio_id__in = lista_id)
```